# react native app crash after splash screen

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am new to React Native. I am created a new blank project in Expo XDE and when I'm trying to run it on my Android device every time it crash after splash screen. It's just a simple blank app.

There is no logs or errors. Expo app just return to first page.

Device: Android 7

XDE: Expo version 2.21.00

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Updated**

**npm start log:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Pfn\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v6.11.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:402:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:357:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:400:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:367:13)
5 verbose cwd F:\react\my-new-project
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Pfn\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
8 verbose node v6.11.3
9 verbose npm  v5.5.1
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

after adding this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
```

to `package.json` log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Pfn\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v6.11.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle my-new-project@0.0.0~prestart: my-new-project@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle my-new-project@0.0.0~start: my-new-project@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-new-project@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-new-project@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;F:\react\my-new-project\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Expo XDE\resources\app\node_modules\xdl\binaries\windows\adb;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Smart Projects\IsoBuster;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle my-new-project@0.0.0~start: CWD: F:\react\my-new-project
10 silly lifecycle my-new-project@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node app.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-new-project@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-new-project@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: my-new-project@0.0.0 start: `node app.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-new-project@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd F:\react\my-new-project
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Pfn\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v6.11.3
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-new-project@0.0.0 start: `node app.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-new-project@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

update2:

npm install warnings :

```
 npm WARN react-native-branch@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
 npm WARN react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.0-alpha.28 requires a peer of react@> 15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sshpk@1.13.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sshpk):
 npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'F:\react\my-new-project\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sshpk' -> 'F:\react\my-new-project\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.sshpk.DELETE'

 added 5 packages and updated 2 packages in 70.53s
```

Comment: That is surprising.  There should be an error somewhere.  There are multiple logs in the XDE.  Also, you may be able to run it from the command line using `npm start` or, if installed, `exp start`.   Some more error information will be helpful.

I tested this on iOS and Android and the code has no errors in it.  It is worth noting that the app does nothing but display the text "Open up App.js to start working on your app!"

Comment: @TomAranda post is updated . there is some errors when i'm using npm start . also :  'exp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you followed the [installed create-react-native-app](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and run `npm install` in your application directory?

Comment: @TomAranda yes but there is some warnings after i run it in project . post updated .

Answer (score 0):

Which OS? Mac, Win, or Linux? If you're on Linux, did you open the XDE client using this command?

```
On Linux, open with chmod a+x xde*.AppImage and ./xde*.AppImage
```

Regardless of your OS, are you sure you have...

- [the latest version of node installed](https://nodejs.org/en/)?
- [the latest version of watchman installed](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html)?

A shot in the dark, but once you've updated the above, I would start a new project and try again.

**UPDATE:** Looking more closely at your logs, I can see you're on Windows since the paths are "C:\...", so ignore the linux comment above. I still think your environment isn't setup correctly though. Reinstalling node and/or watchman may help (most likely node). You might also try installing yarn and see if that makes a difference. Sometimes it does for me.

Comment: thanks Chris. i'm reinstalled everything but still the same

Comment: Have you ever been able to start an expo app on the same machine? Maybe also try `create-react-native-app` too. Not sure why the results would be any different, but worth a shot. Otherwise, I'd reach out to the expo team directly as this might be noteworthy and they can provide better insight.

Comment: Also, if you're willing to screen share, we could work out a time and I'll help you troubleshoot. An option.

Comment: no every time i start expo app it is stuck at splash screen  . i'm updated the post with some logs and info . now i can't even see the splash screen because expo on LAN doesn't work for me and tunnel is down but that is a different problem i guess

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a problem with your environment/setup then. You could try posting to https://forums.expo.io and/or slacking them https://slack.exponentjs.com

Comment: yes sure . that is too kind of you but i have to fix the lan problem first . i'm searching GitHub for answers